# How can I show a video at a specific posision with gst-launch?

Tags: video, gstreamer, gst-launch

I'm trying to play a video file with gst-launch on a embedded board.

First of all, I can play a video with the command below.
- gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! waylandsink

Secondly, I tried to play this video at a specific window position.
- gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Ex_H.264_AAC_400x300.mp4 ! videobox left=20 right=20 top=20 bottom=20 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! waylandsink
([Use gst-launch to output a video frame to certain position on framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284897/use-gst-launch-to-output-a-video-frame-to-certain-position-on-framebuffer))

However, this command makes Error.
- WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "videobox"

How can I use videobox option or use other ways to show a video at a specific window position?

Comment: can you check if you have videobox element by typing gst-inspect-1.0 videobox? What does that command show?

Comment: Thank you to reply. I tryed it and I added videobox. So, now I can use videobox. However, it makes an error. - "wl_shm_pool@3: error 0: invalid format 0x32315559". 
On the internet, this error means format yuv420... I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: You can use the 'videoconvert' to convert to a suitable format supported by the 'videobox' alternatively you use 'videocrop' element which supports a multitude of formats for what you are trying to do. You can find the documentation on the videocrop element under the gst-plugins-good documentation

Comment: Do you have to use Wayland?  I've had all sorts of problems trying to do X,Y window coordinates in Wayland and eventually just gave up.  I don't think it's really part of how they've conceptualized their API.  Also, will your system know the final output resolution?  If so, you may be able to use a videomixer to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I'm using wayland.
I avoided the invalid format error. It because of the order of videobox, video/x-raw. Howerver, this videobox option is just add border. So, I cannot use this option for this problem. I will try to use videomixer.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Gstremer Bad & weston(or others) source code about waylandsink(or others).
Please check it. In case of weston, weston_view_set_position() will decide the video play position.